# Mapbox-gl - How can I allow text/icon overlap without causing text mixtures?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

[click here to see the issue with the text overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY9a0.png)

The texts are on top of each other (click on image link above).

"mapbox-gl": "^2.4.1",

Layer :

```
{
      type: 'symbol',
      layout: {
        'text-field': '{nextShow}',
        'icon-image':'assets/map/queue-bubble.png',
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
        'icon-ignore-placement': true,
        'text-allow-overlap': true,
      },
      paint: {
        'icon-translate': [-25, -25],
        'text-translate': [-28, -28],
        'text-color': 'black',
        'text-halo-color': 'white',
        'text-halo-blur': 1,
        'text-halo-width': 5,
      }
    }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you could achieve this is by allowing icon overlap only. That way the icons will always be visible, but the labels will be visible only when they do not collide with the labels of the other markers. To achieve this just add the following properties to your `layout` object:

```js
    'layout': {
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,  // The icon will be visible even if it collides with other previously drawn symbols.
        'icon-ignore-placement': true,  // Other symbols can be visible even if they collide with the icon.
        'text-optional': true  // Label will be hidden if it collides with other labels
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set order `symbol-z-order` to `"source"` and then use your list `index` to reorder your marker with `symbol-sort-key`

In your example:

```js
{
      type: 'symbol',
      layout: {
        'text-field': '{nextShow}',
        'icon-image':'assets/map/queue-bubble.png',
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
        'icon-ignore-placement': true,
        'text-allow-overlap': true,
        'symbol-z-order': 'source', // to order by symbol-sort-key
        'symbol-sort-key': ['get', 'index'], //index should be defined in source feature properties
      },
      paint: {
        'icon-translate': [-25, -25],
        'text-translate': [-28, -28],
        'text-color': 'black',
        'text-halo-color': 'white',
        'text-halo-blur': 1,
        'text-halo-width': 5,
      }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't fix this issue at all.